# How to update the docker latest version in Ubuntu OS

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to update the latest version docker of docker, unfortunately i couldn't complete this can anyone help me out on this ? i tried my best in google but i am not able to complete this.

```
docker -v
```

Docker version 19.03.13, build cd8016b6bc

but above is not latest version.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade from a recent version like `19.03.13` is easy:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

If that didn't work because you don't have any of the packages, follow [the installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).

Comment: *E: Package 'docker-ce' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
E: Package 'containerd.io' has no installation candidate
*

Comment: I am getting above error, can you please provide step by step which comments i have to run ?

Comment: @Divya run `sudo apt-get update`, then the command again. If nothing changed, follow the guide I mentioned to reinstall docker.

Comment: Err:9 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease                
  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.84.6.124 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/dists/docker/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.84.6.124 443]
E: The repository 'http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: getting above error while run this comment `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @Divya your docker repository for apt is invalid, you need to remove it (it should be somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) then add it again (see [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) on how to add).

Comment: followed same steps now if run `docker -v` getting display latest docker version ls `Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289` but `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory i have checked `docker.list` file now not there. is it fine ?

Comment: @Divya yes it's fine.